# NLTK RegexpParser, chunk phrase by matching exactly one item

Tags: python, regex, nlp, nltk

I'm using NLTK's `RegexpParser` to chunk a noun phrase, which I define with a grammar as

```
 grammar = "NP: {<DT>?<JJ>*<NN|NNS>+}"
 cp = RegexpParser(grammar)
```

This is grand, it is matching a noun phrase as:

- DT if it exists
- JJ in whatever number
- NN or NNS, at least one

Now, what if I want to match the same but having the *whatever number* for JJ transformed into *only one*? So I want to match DT if it exists, **one** JJ and 1+ NN/NNS. If there are more than one JJ, I want to match only one of them, the one nearest to the noun (and DT if there is, and NN/NNS).

The grammar

```
grammar = "NP: {<DT>?<JJ><NN|NNS>+}"
```

would match only when there is just one JJ, the grammar

```
grammar = "NP: {<DT>?<JJ>{1}<NN|NNS>+}"
```

which I thought would work given the [typical Regexp patterns](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html), raises a ValueError.

For example, in "This beautiful green skirt", I'd like to chunk "This green skirt".

So, how would I proceed?

Comment: grammar = "NP: {<DT>?<JJ><NN|NNS>+}" is correct. Can you give example where it did not give determiner?

Comment: Because there are 2 JJs in your example. You said - "I want to match DT if it exists, one JJ and 1+ NN/NNS."

Comment: @RAVI, looks like you're spot on, that explains the problem. You should expand it into an answer that the OP can accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grammer `grammar = "NP: {<DT>?<JJ><NN|NNS>+}"` is correct for your mentioned requirement.

The example which you gave in comment section, where you are not getting DT in output -

```
"This beautiful green skirt is for you."

Tree('S', [('This', 'DT'), ('beautiful', 'JJ'), Tree('NP', [('green','JJ'), 
('skirt', 'NN')]), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('for', 'IN'), ('you', 'PRP'), ('.', '.')])
```

Here in your example, there are `2 consecutive JJs` which does not meet your requirements as you said - `"I want to match DT if it exists, one JJ and 1+ NN/NNS."`

---

For updated requirement - 
`I want to match DT if it exists, one JJ and 1+ NN/NNS. If there are more than one JJ, I want to match only one of them, the one nearest to the noun (and DT if there is, and NN/NNS).`

Here, you will need to use

```
grammar = "NP: {<DT>?<JJ>*<NN|NNS>+}"
```

and do post processing of the NP chunks to remove extra JJ.

**Code:**

```
from nltk import Tree

chunk_output = Tree('S', [Tree('NP', [('This', 'DT'), ('beautiful', 'JJ'), ('green','JJ'), ('skirt', 'NN')]), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('for', 'IN'), ('you', 'PRP'), ('.', '.')])

for child in chunk_output:
    if isinstance(child, Tree):               
        if child.label() == 'NP':
            for num in range(len(child)):
                if not (child[num][1]=='JJ' and child[num+1][1]=='JJ'):
                    print child[num][0]
```

**Output:**

```
This
green
skirt
```

Comment: Right, so there is no way to tell the parser that I want just one directly.

Comment: Yes, it's not possible as you want to skip something in between. If you know how regex matching works, you will understand.